# Calculating the sum of connections for all possible pairings in a network

Tags: python, pandas

Based on a Data Frame listing connections between a source and a destination

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'source':['A','B','B'],'destination':['B','C','C']})
print(df)
  source destination
0      A           B
1      B           C
2      B           C
```

I want to calculate a square matrix containing the number of connections for all pairings, i.e. the resulting DataFrame should be

```
   A  B  C
A  0  1  0
B  0  0  2       
C  0  0  0
```

where the indices represent the sources and the column labels the destinations.

How can I get there?

Comment: the dataframe you print looks nothing like the one you enter the code for?

Comment: Thanks for noting - please see the corrected version.

Comment: You can do it by maintaining a dictionary with source as the key and its value would be a dictionary of dest as key and no of occurance as its value. Ex. {A:{B:1},B:{C:2}} and finally make a matrix out of this relevant info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
v = np.unique(df.values)
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.source, df.destination).reindex(index=v, columns=v, fill_value=0)
print (df1)
destination  A  B  C
source              
A            0  1  0
B            0  0  2
C            0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pivot_table`. `locations` collects all unique entries to expand the final index and columns to include the zero rows and columns.

```py
import numpy as np
locations = np.unique(df.values)
df.pivot_table(index='source',
               columns='destination',
               aggfunc=len, dropna=False
               ).loc[locations, locations].fillna(0)

destination    A    B    C
source                    
A            0.0  1.0  0.0
B            0.0  0.0  2.0
C            0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in which I count connections after converting the letters to integers (indices):

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'source':['A','B','b'],'destination':['B','C','C']})

print(df)

nodes = np.unique(df)
n_nodes = len(nodes) # assuming you have no letters missing

adj = np.zeros((n_nodes, n_nodes))

lett2num = lambda letter : ord(letter.lower()) - 96 # convert letter to number, case insensitive

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 

    i = lett2num(row.source) - 1 
    j = lett2num(row.destination) - 1

    adj[i,j] += 1
```

It outputs for `adj`:

```py
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```